# Как завернуть классы python в модуль?

Tags: python, классы, sympy

Задание дословно:

> Заверните классы из предыдущих задач в модуль Геометрия. Импортируйте модуль. Создайте несколько экземпляров классов. Продемонстрируйте правильность работы кода.

Я пробовала sympy.экземпляр класса - не работает

```
import sympy
# сигнатура класса


class circle:

# конструктор класса
def __init__(self, radius):
    self.radius = radius

# метод для расчета диаметра
def diameter(self):
     return self.radius * 2

# метод для расчета длины окружности
def length(self):
    return self.radius * 2 * 3.14

# метод для расчета площади
def area(self):
   return self.radius * self.radius * 3.14

circle1 = circle(3)
print(circle1.diameter())
print(circle1.length())
print(circle1.area())
import sympy.circle1.area()
```

Comment: Если не работает, то нужно приводить код ошибки. Но вообще вы пытаетесь импортировать файл в самого себя, а в модуле sympy никакого circle1 нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неправильно поняли суть задания.

Нужно не пихать ваш класс в существующий посторонний модуль, а создать свой модуль.

Для этого нужно написать код класса в одном файле, и импортировать его уже из другого файла.

Подробнее вы можете посмотреть в этой статье: https://pythonru.com/uroki/moduli-python-uroki-po-python-dlja-nachinajushhih

Прочитайте там в самом начале разделы "Создание модуля" и "Использование модуля".

Comment: Я делала класс на https:https://colab.research.google.com///colab.research.google.com/ Как добавить на гугл диск или еще куда-то файл geometry.py? Чтобы его импортировать?

Comment: Вам по заданию нужно именно там код писать? Боюсь в рамках этой платформы импорт своего модуля может быть очень нетривиальной задачей.

Comment: Не смогла понять как загрузить на google drive файл geometry.py так, чтобы он добавился в Colaboratory и был виден файлу 03_python_DZ2, поэтому делала локально на MAC OS в jupiter notebook c Anaconda-Navigator-там работает